# C++ return reference variable in prefix overloading

Tags: c++, reference, overloading, prefix

I am confused when all the code I find shows returning a reference variable when overloading the prefix operator. I went through the parashift.com FAQ (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.14) and it isn't clear, even though it says it WILL be clear when you read it. I adapted their example into a nonsensical, pointless little program to test.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Number {
   public:
      Number& operator++ ();    // prefix ++
      Number  operator++ (int); // postfix ++
      int value() { return value_; }
      void setValue(int value) { value_ = value; }
   private:
      int value_;
};

Number& Number::operator++ () {
   ++value_;
   return *this;
}

Number Number::operator++ (int unused) {
   Number temp;
   temp.setValue(value_);
   ++value_;
   return temp;
}

int main()
{
   Number someNum;
   someNum.setValue(20);
   cout << "someNum : " << someNum.value() << "\n";
   someNum++;
   ++someNum;
   cout << "someNum : " << someNum.value() << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

The problem is, it works if I just declare it as a Number object as well like so:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Number {
   public:
      Number operator++ ();    // prefix ++
      Number  operator++ (int); // postfix ++
      int value() { return value_; }
      void setValue(int value) { value_ = value; }
   private:
      int value_;
};

Number Number::operator++ () {
   ++value_;
   return *this;
}

Number Number::operator++ (int unused) {
   Number temp;
   temp.setValue(value_);
   ++value_;
   return temp;
}

int main()
{
   Number someNum;
   someNum.setValue(20);
   cout << "someNum : " << someNum.value() << "\n";
   someNum++;
   ++someNum;
   cout << "someNum : " << someNum.value() << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

I assume I simply need a better understanding of reference variables. Can anyone explain simply why the prefix operator SHOULD be coded as returning a reference variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's an efficiency issue. You are creating a new instance of the class in order to return it for no reason.

Second, there's the semantic issue. Your code invokes the empty constructor or the copy constructor to make the temporary and then destructs the temporary. If that has semantic meaning that's inappropriate, then the code doesn't really work, it just appears to.

Third, the code returns the wrong thing. Consider: `++foo.do_something();`. With your code, we call 'do_something' on the temporary object. We wanted to call `do_something()` on the pre-incremented `foo`.

Answer (score 9):

The difference between :

```
Number& Number::operator++ () {
   ++value_;
   return *this;
}
```

and

```
Number Number::operator++ () {
   ++value_;
   return *this;
}
```

is that, when you use the first code, the following expression:

```
++(++(++someNum));
```

increments `someNum` THRICE. See the output here: http://ideone.com/y9UlY

However, when you use the second one, this

```
++(++(++someNum));
```

increments `someNum` just ONCE!! See the output here: http://ideone.com/eOLdj

It is because when you return the reference from `operator++()`, the second and third `++` invokes on the same object called `someNum` and therefore, it increments the same object, all the times. But when you return by value, the second and third `++` invokes on the **temporary** object which you returned from `operator++()`. Hence, the second and third call doesn't increment `someNum`, instead it increments the temporary objects which get destroyed at the end of the expression.

Now if the temporary objects get destroyed, why create then in the first place? After all, its pre-increment operator, which means the temporary and the original object will have the same value. So the good design decision is, return by reference when defining pre-increment operator, to avoid creating temporary, and improve performance.

Comment: So the second would be the more appropriate if you compare it to the post-increment where ((someNum++)++)++ also increments someNum only ONCE! So if looking from that side returning a copy would be better since the semantics of post and pre increment operators would be comparable!

Comment: @RüdigerStevens: Not really. Post-increment, by definition, have to return a temporary, because the returned object and the original object will have different value. But in case of pre-increment, the return object and the original object will have the same value; hence there is no point in creating a temporary in pre-increment operator, and then returning it.